# How to insert the markers at two particular points

Tags: plotting

I have a plot I wanted to put a marker at the transition (a point at which straight line starts to become little curve) and saturation (curve becomes straight line) points in the graph. I have manually identified the point. I wanted to put the star at transition point, and circle saturation point. And to name the graph as mode 1 with arrow.

```
    ks1={0.01,1.,2.,4.,6.,8.,10.,25.,50.,100.,200.,300.,400.,500.,600.,800.,1000.,2000.,4000.,5000.,10000.,15000.,20000.,30000.,40000.,70000.,100000.,1.*10^6,1.*10^8,1.*10^12};
    b1={1.8743,1.8784,1.88248,1.89049,1.89828,1.90587,1.91327,1.96335,2.03035,2.12536,2.23701,2.30098,2.34255,2.37175,2.3934,2.42334,2.44307,2.48725,2.51208,2.5173,2.52799,2.53164,2.53348,2.53533,2.53625,2.53745,2.53793,2.53894,2.53909,2.53543};
    markermode1={{0.943,1.87835},{41086.3,2.53793}};
    s1=ListLogLinearPlot[Transpose[{ks1, b1}], Joined -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.01]}, AxesStyle -> Black, 
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[10], Point[markermode1]}]
```

Comment: do you get what you need if you use `markermode1 = {{Log@0.943, 1.87835}, {Log@41086.3, 2.53793}}`?

Comment: I wanted my marker star symbol I used Style["\[SixPointedStar]", 60]. but getting error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
markermode1b = {{Log@0.943, 1.87835}, {Log@41086.3, 2.53793}};
ListLogLinearPlot[Transpose[{ks1, b1}], Joined -> True,
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.01]}, AxesStyle -> Black, 
 Epilog -> {Red, Text[Style["\[SixPointedStar]", 36], #] & /@ markermode1b}]
```

[image]

**Update:** ***"to make the lower one filled with colour and the upper one unfilled with colour"***

```
star = First[First[ImportString[ExportString[
   Style["\[SixPointedStar]", FontSize -> 16], "PDF"], "PDF", "TextMode" -> "Outlines"]]];
emptyhex = Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Thickness[.1], Red}], White, star}, ImageSize -> 20];
filledhex = Graphics[{EdgeForm[], Red, star}, ImageSize -> 20];

ListLogLinearPlot[Transpose[{ks1, b1}], Joined -> True, 
 PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.01]}, AxesStyle -> Black, 
 Epilog -> {Inset[filledhex, markermode1b[[1]]], 
   Inset[emptyhex, markermode1[[2]]]}, PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

[image]

**Update 2:** Alternatively, you can use `Mesh` combined with a `Dynamic` setting for `PlotMarkers`:

```
hex = {filledhex, emptyhex}; 
ListLogLinearPlot[Transpose[{ks1, b1}], 
 Joined -> True, PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.01]}, 
 AxesStyle -> Black, PlotRangeClipping -> False, PlotRange -> All, 
 Mesh -> {markermode1[[All, 1]]}, 
 PlotMarkers -> Dynamic[{Last[hex = RotateRight[hex]], .1}]]
```

[image]

Comment: How to make  the lower one filled with colour and the  upper one unfilled with colour?

Comment: @acoustics, please see the update.

Answer (score 3):

Creating a second `ListLogLinearPlot` solves this problem without having to modify `markermode1`:

```
s1 = ListLogLinearPlot[
  Transpose[{ks1, b1}],
  Joined -> True,
  PlotStyle -> {Black, Thickness[0.01]},
  AxesStyle -> Black
  ];

s2 = ListLogLinearPlot[
  markermode1,
  PlotMarkers -> Text[Style["\[SixPointedStar]", 36]],
  PlotStyle -> Red
  ];

Show[s1, s2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can also put these together like this:

```
s1 = ListLogLinearPlot[
  {Transpose[{ks1, b1}], markermode1},
  Joined -> {True, False},
  PlotStyle -> {{Black, Thickness[0.01]}, Red},
  PlotMarkers -> {{Graphics[], 0}, {Text[Style["\[SixPointedStar]", 36]], 1}},
  AxesStyle -> Black
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can accommodate the filled and unfilled marker types by making one data series for each type. I used the nice markers that kglr created in his answer:

```
data = Transpose[{ks1, b1}];
filledMarkers = {{0.943, 1.87835}};
unfilledMarkers = {{41086.3, 2.53793}};

s1 = ListLogLinearPlot[
  {data, filledMarkers, unfilledMarkers},
  Joined -> {True, False, False},
  PlotStyle -> {{Black, Thickness[0.01]}, Red, Red},
  PlotMarkers -> {
    {Graphics[], 0},
    {filledhex, 0.1},
    {emptyhex, 0.1}
    },
  AxesStyle -> Black
  ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]